# How to prove that CC($\mathbb R$) is true in permutation models

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've familiarised myself with models of set theory and am beginning to understand the basics, but am still very far away from being a proper model theorist. I currently live under the impression that I understand the idea of the construction of the first and second Fraenkel models.

Hence, unfortunately, I must ask how one proves that the axiom of countable choice for subsets of $\mathbb R$ holds in permutation models.

As far as I'm aware, it is not necessary to assume the axiom of choice when constructing permutation models.

There is a particular issue that caused me some trouble. When we start constructing some permutation model, we assume that we already have some set theory as a metatheory. In this set theory, the atoms are mere sets, and thus, if we start building up the von Neumann hierarchy with atoms, all atoms will appear at some point in the kernel, which is a problem, because atoms should not be in the kernel.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Or are the atoms greater than some strongly inaccessible cardinal?

EDIT 2: Or do we start from atoms and the emtpy set and do a construction analogous to the constructible universe?

Comment: You mean when we construct a model of ZFA? Permutation models *start* from a model of ZFA. Do you have a particular construction in mind that you’re concerned about having atoms in show up in the kernel?

Comment: In constructing a model of ZFA(C) from one of ZF(C), we avoid that, of course, but you need to be more specific what you have in mind / why you think it’s inevitable.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I would be very pleased to be introduced to a/the "standard way" of constructing a permutation model.

Comment: The standard way to construct a permutation model is in Jech, where you start with a model of ZFA with some appropriate configuration of atoms, then choose a permutation group and a normal filter, and then finally the permuation model is the submodel consisting of the hereditarily symmetric sets with respect to the filter. But again, the issue in your last paragraph seems more related to constructing models of ZFA in the first place. (Which is also in Jech, albeit as an exercise.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Where would be the page? I'm having the book right in front of me.

Comment: 45-47... the exercise i mentioned is problem 1 on p 51

Comment: Yes, that's what I read. Why does the axiom of choice hold in this ZFA version of the von Neumann universe?

Comment: Well, you generally actually start with a model of ZFAC as is remarked on the bottom of p 47 (often Jech assumes global choice also). There are no admissibility issues (note in the exercise, that from a model of ZFC, the construction gives a model of ZFAC); what would be questionable at this juncture would be assuming *failure* of AC.

Comment: In this specific model (from the exercise), AC does hold, which in particular makes the model unsuitable for proving the independence of AC.

Comment: How? The model where AC fails is a submodel of this model (i.e. the permutation model).

Comment: OK, if you take this model as the model from which to construct the permutation model, I imagine it works. (You would presumably need to increase the cardinality of A depending on your needs.)

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Of course it's right: I wrote it!

Answer (score 2):

Trivially.

Since permutation models preserve choice in the pure sets (or, kernel), and since $\Bbb R$ is in bijection with $\cal P(\omega)$, it must be well-orderable.

Comment: I think they are asking what if you don’t have choice in the background (and of course the answer is you do, or at least you must for this to hold).

Comment: So, as far as I understand it, the constructible universe satisfies AC. So I, being ENTIRELY UNFAMILIAR with the way permutation models are constructed, wanted to know how it is being done and whether it uses the constructible universe (which I suspect).

Comment: @Cloudscape: Permutation models are constructed by starting with a model of ZFA, but traditionally starting with an assumption of choice. Other universes satisfy AC too, not just the constructible universe. It might be worth, if you're ENTIRELY UNFAMILIAR with the technique to open a book and learn about it. Jech's Axiom of Choice is a good option.

Comment: I'm having the Jech right in front of me, but I didn't read the entire thing yet (neither do I mean to, for I'm only interested in a subset of techniques). I'd be confident to assert that a construction akin to the one suggested in my second edit is not in there. In the chapter that introduces permutation models, it seems that he simply assumes AC in the meta-theory, and seems to define the permutation model inside a von Neumann-type universe. But assuming AC in order to prove its independence seems somewhat questionable.

Comment: ...that being said, now that I'm thinking about all this, the constructions do seem to work with appropriate modification. (By the way, I've been working on the old UBP problem, and hope to publish a satisfactory solution in the near future.)

Comment: @Cloudscape: This sounds like an X-Y Problem type of question. At the end of the day it's hard to learn "just the tip" of a complicated mathematical technique. You can either be open about what you're trying to do and get a straight answer. Or you can sit down and study the technique yourself.

Comment: Well, I'm happy to admit that it IS an X-Y Problem type of question, but I actually have SEVERAL purposes for which I want to use permutation models.

Comment: Well. If you're uncomfortable asking the Y-problem in public, for whatever reason, drop me an email.

Comment: No, no, I'm simply trying to differentiate some choice axioms.

Comment: Specifically, if I recall correctly (the last weeks were intense), my purpose was to understand implications between different statements about Lindelöf spaces. There was a paper that used the claim I asked about. And I WILL study the technique of permutation models, because I plan to make extensive use of it. This particular question will help me a bit by automatically showing the relative consistency of CC(R) with the failure of the choice axioms under consideration.

Comment: Well, if you'd have told me what you're trying to do, I could have perhaps give you better advice. But that's up to you.

Comment: I've told you everything I tried to do with this particular question. As for the other areas, I do not doubt that you could prove some independence results with less effort than I, but it wouldn't be MY accomplishment then. Also, I would not learn about the methods which I want to understand because they are closely related to my research.

Answer (score -1):

I think that I may have discovered an important point here. For if we just assume that AC holds in the meta-theory, then all the statements we prove using permutation models are of the form "If the axiom of choice is true, then statement XYZ is not implied by the axioms." But this is unsatisfactory, because we don't know what happens if AC is not true.

Thus, in my upcoming paper I'll first construct the "ZFA version" of the constructible universe, and then take my permutation models to be subclasses of this universe.

EDIT: Or alternatively, if that will not give me enough sets, I will construct a ZFA model inside the constructible universe.